# How to find data between two dates in mongdb

Tags: mongodb

I want to find all ipAddress "192.168.0.52" between two dates,
any help please

```
 varMatch = { $match : { "ipAddress": "192.168.0.52"}},
 varGroup = { $group: {
 "_id": {timestamp:{"$auditMessages.timestamp":
    {$gt: ISODate("2020-05-14T13:08:30.748Z"),
                   $lt: ISODate("2020-04-08T13:00:34.567Z")
}}}}},
db.compte.aggregate([varMatch,varGroup])
```

I have a problem in date i can't find a correct syntax fo date, however in json file I don't have  after timestamp.

This is example of my DB
[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Looks like your timestamp is stored as `String`, it's best to change them to `Date` if possible

Comment: @thammada can you tell me how, please? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find all documents with IP address '192.168.0.52' and timestamps between two dates by adding an additional expression to your match stage.

```
const matchStage = { 
    $match: {
       ipAddress: '192.168.0.52',
       'auditMessages.timestamp': {
          $gt: new Date('2020-05-14T13:08:30.748Z'),
          $lt: new Date('2020-04-08T13:00:34.567Z')
       }
    }
};
```

Once that's done, you can perform your grouping operation as desired.

Comment: Would you check OP's answer which is addressing you? I think you can Edit/Flag/Comment it.

Comment: @ArdentCoder it seems the answer has been removed but thanks for bringing that to my attention. Cheers.

Comment: I'm new here, so sorry for this mistake

Comment: @IyanuAdelekan I didn't understand your answer, could you please explain me. Thank you in advance

Comment: @m1h3r you should be able to find the ip documents between your audit message date range by aggregating with the `matchStage` in my example. Can you try running `db.compte.aggregate([matchStage])` and let me know if you get your desired result?

Comment: @IyanuAdelekan I try db.compte.aggregate([matchStage]) but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample document? It will help us understand the structure of your data better.

Comment: Done - @IyanuAdelekan

Comment: @IyanuAdelekan Can you help me please?